# Columns move when hover in IE8 and Chrome Windows 7

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, google-chrome, css, hover

I can't get my head around why the columns move when I hover over the last image on the row.
http://www.heritageglass.com.au/projects

On my mac it works in all browsers.
In windows 7 it works in the latest versions of IE and Chrome, it **doesn't work** in IE8 and Chrome v26. - the client views in IE8 so I have to get as close as I can to it.

Unfortunately I cannot show you the test results as they are done on the development site on our server, but this is what I have tried and no luck:

- DOCTYPE is valid.
- Added `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />` to development site.
- increasing the width of the container the images are in
  (portfolio-full).
- eliminating the padding-right of the last-child (but only applies to 
  the very last image - useless).
- changing the negative padding to negative top and left.
- position: relative to static and hover state.
- eliminating margins and applying padding instead.
- no borders on the actual columns, just image.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you be sure there isn't anything inserted before the doctype? If there is anything there at all, even white space, IE will go into quirks mode. Looking at source in Chrome shows the doctype isn't on line 1.

Comment: Thanks @Rob, I have checked my header.php file in Wordpress and its on line 1. Is there anything called before the header.php file that I can check spacing in?

Comment: Done! Don't know how or why but I removed all the spaces in the wordpress templates before it calls the header and that seemed to do the job! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Check for any spaces or extraneous data inserted before the doctype. If anything is there at all, including white space, IE will go into quirks mode.